# What command will restart Apache from a PuTTY terminal to manage a cPanel server?

Tags: apache, cpanel, linux

Once when we logged on to the server via putty terminal with authorised SSH credentials

What is the command given to the putty terminal for restarting the Apache server after loading some extensions?

It only gives them the following help of what commands can be executed:

```
login as: nishanth

Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"

Passphrase for key "imported-openssh-key":

[nishanth@bh-in-28 ~]$ help

GNU bash, version 4.1.2(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

These shell commands are defined internally.  Type `help' to see this list.
Type `help name' to find out more about the function `name'.

Use `info bash' to find out more about the shell in general.
Use `man -k' or `info' to find out more about commands not in this list.

A star (*) next to a name means that the command is disabled.

 job_spec [&]                            history [-c] [-d offset] [n] or hist>

 (( expression ))                        if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif C>

 . filename [arguments]                  jobs [-lnprs] [jobspec ...] or jobs >

 :                                       kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigs>

 [ arg... ]                              let arg [arg ...]

 [[ expression ]]                        local [option] name[=value] ...

 alias [-p] [name[=value] ... ]          logout [n]

 bg [job_spec ...]                       mapfile [-n count] [-O origin] [-s c>

 bind [-lpvsPVS] [-m keymap] [-f filen>  popd [-n] [+N | -N]

 break [n]                               printf [-v var] format [arguments]

 builtin [shell-builtin [arg ...]]       pushd [-n] [+N | -N | dir]

 caller [expr]                           pwd [-LP]

 case WORD in [PATTERN [| PATTERN]...)>  read [-ers] [-a array] [-d delim] [->

 cd [-L|-P] [dir]                        readarray [-n count] [-O origin] [-s>

 command [-pVv] command [arg ...]        readonly [-af] [name[=value] ...] or>

 compgen [-abcdefgjksuv] [-o option]  >  return [n]

 complete [-abcdefgjksuv] [-pr] [-DE] >  select NAME [in WORDS ... ;] do COMM>

 compopt [-o|+o option] [-DE] [name ..>  set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option>

 continue [n]                            shift [n]

 coproc [NAME] command [redirections]    shopt [-pqsu] [-o] [optname ...]

 declare [-aAfFilrtux] [-p] [name[=val>  source filename [arguments]

 dirs [-clpv] [+N] [-N]                  suspend [-f]

 disown [-h] [-ar] [jobspec ...]         test [expr]

 echo [-neE] [arg ...]                   time [-p] pipeline

 enable [-a] [-dnps] [-f filename] [na>  times

 eval [arg ...]                          trap [-lp] [[arg] signal_spec ...]

 exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [argume>  true

 exit [n]                                type [-afptP] name [name ...]

[nishanth@bh-in-28 ~]$ ps

PID TTY          TIME CMD

496364 pts/2    00:00:00 bash

507012 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
```

Is that commands are limited from the above list or how am I suppose to do what in order to access all the commands from the putty terminal.

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per post.   You have several questions here in a bullet list along with an additional question at the end.

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller♦ Hi but the problem faced was like that. Please could you edit my post so that three bulletin points must be answerable

Comment: I've edited your post to just ask one question.   If you have other questions you can ask those in separate posts

Comment: Your question about how to copy and paste in PuTTY should be asked on https://superuser.com

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller♦ Thanks Stephen Does any of these questions belongs to as OFF-TOPIC I just needed to confirm it

Comment: Other than your PuTTY copy and paste question, your other questions look like they would be on topic here to me.

Comment: As far as it and paste, just selcet the text with a mouse and it is put into the cut/paste buffer. Use the insert button to paste. Going by memory. For Apache, see here... https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/star-stop-restart-apache2-webserver/